# Determine if relation is in BCNF form?

Tags: algorithm, rdbms, database-normalization, bcnf

How do I determine if the following relation is in BCNF form?

```
R(U,V,W,X,Y,Z)

UVW ->X
VW -> YU
VWY ->Z
```

I understand that for a functional dependency A->B A must be a superkey. And the relation must be in 3NF form. But I am unsure how to apply the concepts.

Comment: Right now you are effectively asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you show no research or other effort. [ask] [Help] [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) Show the steps of your work following a textbook/reference with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the 1st place you are stuck/unsure. Quote definitions, theorems, algorithms & heuristics you rely on. All the steps are also SO faqs. Google with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if a relation is in BCNF, for the definition you should check that for each non-trivial dependency in `F+`, that is, for all the dependencies specified (`F`) and those derived from them, the determinant should be a superkey. Fortunately, there is a theorem that says that it is sufficient perform this check only for the specified dependencies.

In your case this means that you must check if `UVW`, `VW` and `VWY` are superkeys.

And to see if in a dependency `X -> Y` the set attributes `X` is a superkey you can compute the closure of the attributes (`X+`) and check if it contains the right hand part `Y`.

So you have to compute `UVW+` and see if it contains `{U,V,W,X,Y,Z}` and similarly for the other two dependencies. I leave to you this simple exercise.

Comment: To confirm if VW+, UVW+ and VWY+ all contain {U,V,W,X,Y,Z} then it is BCNF

Comment: @bob : yes, the relation is in BCNF, since the (only) candidate key is VW and a canonical cover is: V W → U,
V W → Y,
V W → Z,
V W → X .

Comment: If for example, if this relation was not in BCNF how would I determine if it was in 3NF. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @bob, the check for 3NF requires the computation of all the candidate keys (which is in principle a task with an exponential cost). A relation is in 3FN if for each functional dependency `X -> A1 A2 ... An` in F either `X` is a superkey or `Ai` is a prime attribute (that is, an attribute of some candidate key).

Comment: What theorem is that?

Comment: @philipxy, a theorem cited in “Tsou and Fischer, Decomposition of a Relation Scheme into Boyce-Codd Normal Form, ACM Sigact News, Vol 14, N. 3, 1982”, in which it is attributed to Jou and Fisher (proved in the report  CS-80-6, Dept of CS Pennsylvania State University, 1980, report to which I do not have access). Here is the definition: "Remark 2,9: For a given set U of attributes and a given set F of FD's over U, if for every FD f in F either CL(L(f)) = (f) or CL(L(f)) = U, then U is in BCNF."  CL(X) is the closure of a set of attributes X, L(f) is the left hand side of a dependency f.

Answer (score 0):

Using the algorithm to compute the closure of a given set of attributes and the definition of BCNF as shown in the following figure,

[image]

we can implement the above algorithm in `python` to compute closure of attributes and then  determine whether a given set of attributes forms a superkey or not, as shown in the following code snippet:

```
def closure(s, fds):
    c = s
    for f in fds:
        l, r = f[0], f[1]
        if l.issubset(c):
            c = c.union(r)
    if s != c:
        c = closure(c, fds)
    return c

def is_superkey(s, rel, fds):
    c = closure(s, fds)
    print(f'({"".join(sorted(s))})+ = {"".join(sorted(c))}')
    return c == rel
```

Now check if for each given FD `A -> B` from relation `R`, `A` is a superkey or not, to determine whether `R` is in `BCNF` or not:

```
def is_in_BCNF(rel, fds):
   for fd in fds:
      l, r = fd[0], fd[1]
      isk = is_superkey(l, rel, fds)
      print(f'For the Functional Dependency {"".join(sorted(l))} -> {"".join(sorted(r))}, ' +\
                  f'{"".join(sorted(l))} {"is" if isk else "is not"} a superkey')
      if not isk:
         print('=> R not in BCNF!')
         return False
   print('=> R in BCNF!')  
   return True
```

To process the given FDs in standard form, to convert to suitable data structure, we can use the following function:

```
import re

def process_fds(fds):
    pfds = []
    for fd in fds:
        fd = re.sub('\s+', '', fd)
        l, r = fd.split('->')
        pfds.append([set(list(l)), set(list(r))])
    return pfds
```

Now, let's test with a couple of relations:

```
relation = {'U','V','W','X','Y','Z'}
fds = process_fds(['UVW->X', 'VW->YU', 'VWY->Z'])
is_in_BCNF(relation, fds)

# (UVW)+ = UVWXYZ
# For the Functional Dependency UVW -> X, UVW is a superkey
# (VW)+ = UVWXYZ
# For the Functional Dependency VW -> UY, VW is a superkey
# (VWY)+ = UVWXYZ
# For the Functional Dependency VWY -> Z, VWY is a superkey
# => R in BCNF!

relation = {'A','B','C'}
fds = process_fds(['A -> BC', 'B -> A'])
is_in_BCNF(relation, fds)

# (A)+ = ABC
# For the Functional Dependency A -> BC, A is a superkey
# (B)+ = ABC
# For the Functional Dependency B -> A, B is a superkey
# => R in BCNF!
```

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)
Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Python is not an appropriate tag for this question, it is irrelevant to the question. Just because a language/etc is used in presenting an answer doesn't make it relevant to the question or other answers.